# Bootstrap grid overlap when adding links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, overlapping

Unsure as to why adding links to the h3 tag creates overlap with bootstrap grid system.  The other links seem to work fine, but adding in the links created this discrepancy in the code.

```
        <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href="826DC.html" ><img src="work/SCCthumb.jpg"></a>
        <h3 class="smltitle">826DC</h3>
        <h1 class="smlhead">Print</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <a  href="AsiaOutdoors.html" ><img src="work/Asiaoutdoorsthumb.jpg"></a>
        <h3 class="smltitle">Asia Outdoors</h3>
        <h1 class="smlhead">Print</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href="AHA.html" ><img src="work/AHAthumb.jpg"></a>
        <h3 class="smltitle">American Heart Association; Heart's Delight</h3>
        <h1 class="smlhead">Print</h1>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href="CafeGelatoh.html" ><img src="work/CafeGelatohthumb.jpg"></a>
        <h3 class="smltitle"><a href="CafeGelatoh.html">Cafe Gelatohhh!!!</a></h3>
        <h1 class="smlhead">Branding, Print</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href="Cardinvite.html" ><img src="work/cardsthumb.jpg"></a>
        <h3 class="smltitle"><a href="Cardinvite.html">Cards, Invitations Etc</a></h3>
    </div>

</div>
```

If I could post images, I would be able to show you.  Basically, the code images with the link inside the h3 tag (the bottom ones) overlap.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, put the *a tags* outside of the H3

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="826DC.html" ><img src="work/SCCthumb.jpg"></a>
    <h3 class="smltitle">826DC</h3>
    <h1 class="smlhead">Print</h1>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <a  href="AsiaOutdoors.html" ><img src="work/Asiaoutdoorsthumb.jpg"></a>
    <h3 class="smltitle">Asia Outdoors</h3>
    <h1 class="smlhead">Print</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="AHA.html" ><img src="work/AHAthumb.jpg"></a>
    <h3 class="smltitle">American Heart Association; Heart's Delight</h3>
    <h1 class="smlhead">Print</h1>
</div>

</div>

<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="CafeGelatoh.html" ><img src="work/CafeGelatohthumb.jpg"></a>
    <a href="CafeGelatoh.html"><h3 class="smltitle">Cafe Gelatohhh!!!</h3></a>
    <h1 class="smlhead">Branding, Print</h1>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="Cardinvite.html" ><img src="work/cardsthumb.jpg"></a>
    <a href="Cardinvite.html"><h3 class="smltitle">Cards, Invitations Etc</h3></a>
</div>

</div>
```

Hope this helped you solve the issue!

ps, You could add another *col-md-4* to complete the 12 block too. As this fiddle illustrates
http://fiddle.jshell.net/6pyny04p/

Comment: Unfortunately, putting the <a> tags outside of the <h3> tags didn't seem to work.  Thank you for the attempt!

Comment: @aleejelly please look at my fiddle and explain your issue more clearly

http://fiddle.jshell.net/6pyny04p/2/

Comment: I can try: the first row div is above the second row div.  The second row div images are fine, however, I wanted to make the h3 tags links.  When I made them links with link tags, the images overlapped.  When I view the source of the divs with the class col-md-4, the second row divs are smaller than the top row.  I have no idea why they are smaller, but they overlap.. The link issue may be a completely separate one, but changing the links and the div size shrinking happened simultaneously

Comment: In my fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/6pyny04p/2/ the H3 tags ARE links!! Click here http://fiddle.jshell.net/6pyny04p/2/ and try them out.

Comment: Yes... Again, thank you for your help but changing where the h3 tags are did not fix my problem. My problem is with overlap, not creating links.  The issue I'm having is with bootstrap grid divs overlapping/changing sizes, which is as one would expect, completely Independent from my making the header a link.   I will edit my question when I'm at a computer

Comment: @aleejelly i have now coloured them blue for you to see there is no overlapping http://fiddle.jshell.net/6pyny04p/5/